# Is it OK to introduce your answer by asserting your wisdom?

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to introduce your answer by asserting your wisdom?

It sounds a bit crazy; not to laugh at anyone here, but -- especially given I disagree with a lot of material on this site [both the answers and the quality of the answers' research] -- I am uncomfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I know what you mean, and I too don't like it, and I don't know why somebody would write that.

- Are they happy and excited ("Oh I know! I know!")?
- Is it tradition ("You have spoken boldly with a bull's voice, Sariputta, you have roared the lion's roar of certainty")?
- Is it a conceit ("I know better than you do")?
- Is it trolling ("This is a way to annoy people")?

I think it's rude (likely to irritate some people), unconventional (most users don't post like that), and useless or counter-productive.

So far as I know there isn't currently a rule against it -- "You're wrong" might be offensive (and deleted by a moderator), "I'm right" might be a matter of opinion and permitted to remain (to be assessed by the reader) -- and therefore a kind of phraseology which we have had to tolerate.

Comment: i think you're right about 'phraseology' etc

Comment: You are wrong, aren't you here?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a rule. It's definitely not the norm nor exceptionally good use of the platform, has no benefit and if everyone did it it would clutter the board with off-topic bs and be very annoying because lot of it is just delusion of people expressed as untrue statements, unfounded allegation, one's suspicions or slander etc

It's also disrespectful to OP when people post low quality answers in bad faith because it's offtopic and nobody asked for it, it's essential abuse of the community.

As i see it people ask questions wanting to know what the texts say or the interpretations, nobody ever asks 'tell me about this great rightness of yours'.

Imo people should try to post just excerpts, facts or lines of thinking and interpretation as interpretation to let the questioneer make up his own mind. I think talking oneself up or putting others down is inappropriate and is an offense.

Comment: `There should be a rule.` How about "Don't feed the troll" -- isn't that sufficient as a rule? Must you involve moderators (in making and enforcing "rules") when you don't want to tolerate what other users post? My job is to implement the policies defined in the [meta-tag:faq] and Help topics. Is someone's saying, essentially, "I can answer your question", contradictory to the [Code of Conduct](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/conduct) or [Expected Behaviour](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) topics? Because if it isn't I'm not sure I should (and don't necessarily) intervene.

Comment: I was thinking more like "avoid excessive boasting and talking down others".

Comment: "Talking down others" is already something I'll try to prevent, isn't it -- especially, other users.

Answer (score 0):

Troubled householders,

It's more then helpful to know a little about the questioners wisdom (answerers as well).

What else as the pride of a reader himself could cause him troubles?

Another reason might be (which is of course the same root) that one might feel not comfortable having actually no base to lift himself on another "need" => The starving "Bodhisatta".

Good field for Satipathana to get the cause of Suffering seen where it arises.

*(Note: this isn't givenfor trade, exchange, stacks and what ever binds one here but for escape from this wheel.)*